# Javascript pig latin regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to make a function that will convert English words into Pig Latin. The problem I have is when I check to see if the first letter is a vowel. I check using a regular expression: `if (str[0] === /[aeiou]/i)` but it doesn't work. Something is wrong with my regex but I look at references and it seems like that should work. I don't know what's going on. Can someone explain why the regex I am using does not work and what would be a similar working solution? If you run the code below, it doesn't give the right result, just saying beforehand.

```
function translate(str) {
    var tag = "";
    if (str[0] === /[aeiou]/i) {
        tag = "way";
        return str + tag;
    }
    else {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i< str.length; i++) {
            if (str[i] !== /[aeiou]/i)
                tag += str[i];
            else
                break;
            count = i;
        }
        console.log(count);
        return str.slice(count + 1) + tag + "ay";
    }    
}
```

So when I run say `translate(overjoyed)` it should return "overjoyedway". And if I run `translate(glove)` it should return "oveglay".

Comment: you need to look at regexp examples again - your code is using them completely incorrectly

Comment: That's not how you test a string against a regex. Try looking up `String.Prototype.match()` on MDC.

Comment: Also no need for regex: `if ("aeiou".indexOf(str[0]) !=-1) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is not the way you **use** regular expressions.  The code `if (str[0] === /[aeiou]/i)` tests whether the first element of the `str` string array is both **equal value and equal type** as the regular expression: `/[aeiou]/i`.  Characters are not the same **type** as regular expressions, so such a comparison will evaluate to `false`.

Think of the regular expression as a tool that can be used to search an **entire** string array for a match (**all** of `str`, not *just* `str[0]`).  The web has a bunch of great examples, but to get you started, you might try using `str.search(regexp)` which will return the index of the **first** match (if found) or `-1` (if no match).

Your code then becomes (without too much deviation from the original, and without trying to be clever or optimal):

```
function translate(str) {
    var tag = "";
    var pos = str.search(/[aeiou]/i); // This is ONE way to use regular expressions.
    if (pos == 0) { // First letter is a vowel.
        tag = "way";
        return str + tag;
    } else if (pos > 0) { // Some letter (not the first) is a vowel.
        // Instead of the loop checking each element, we already know where 
        // the match is found: at position = pos.
        console.log(pos); // Log the match position of the first vowel.
        tag = str.slice(0, pos); // The string before the first vowel.
        return str.slice(pos) + tag + "ay";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: You're welcome - and welcome to stack overflow!  If you find this post answered your question, please mark it as an accepted answer.  This will help future visitors with similar questions, and encourage quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
function pig(str) {
    if (/^[aeiou]/i.test(str)) {
        return str + 'way';
    }
    else {
        return str.replace(/^(.[^aeiou]+)([aeiou].*)$/i, "$2$1ay");
    }
}
console.log(pig('overjoyed'));
console.log(pig('glove'));
```

Comment: thaks for the downvotes ... how can I make this answer more useful? I mean, it's correct and teaches correct use of regexp

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing it's because: 1. You didn't explain what was wrong with his approach and 2. You gave "working" code without an explanation about your approach.

Comment: yeah, i sometimes struggle with picking between what is obvious and what needs to be explained

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just recently did something similar in Ruby and thought I'd rewrite in in JavaScript and supply it as an answer.

```
function translate( words )
{
  return words.split(' ').map(function(word){
    return word.split(/\b([^a,e,i,o,u]{0,}qu|[^a,e,i,o,u]+)?([a,e,i,o,u][a-z]+)?/i).reverse().join('') + 'ay'
  }).join(' ')
}
```

So in mine I take a string `words` that can be a single word or a full sentence.

I split it up into an array of words by splitting on spaces.

I then used map to run code on each word in that array, in there I have it split the word using my regex (which I'll explain at the end) which splits it into the first sound if it is anything other than a vowel sound and the rest of the word.

On the word quiet that split actually results in the following array: `["","qu","iet",""]`, and on the word aqua it results in `["",undefined,"aqua",""]`.

I can ignore those undefined and empty strings though because when we join it back together they get ignored.

So after it is split up I reverse the array and then join it back together as a word (joining it using an empty string `''`) and then tack on `'ay'` to the end of the resulting string.

Now to explain the regex:

- `\b` says we are looking for the start of a word, it could alternatively be `^` for the start of the string.
- `([^a,e,i,o,u]{0,}qu|[^a,e,i,o,u]+)?` is an optional capture group looking for that first consonant sound, let's further break it up.
- So within it we have two alternatives we are looking for, either `[^a,e,i,o,u]{0,}qu` or `[^a,e,i,o,u]+`, the first one checks for the first sound containing `qu` with or without preceding non-vowel characters (so the `qu` from quiet, or the squ from square get matched instead of stopping before the u), and the second one is checking for all non-vowel letters before the first vowel in the case that there is no qu at the start.

  - Now that final part of it `([a,e,i,o,u][a-z]+)?` is just grabbing from that first vowel on as the rest of that match

I hope someone somewhere finds this useful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
    if(["a","e","i","o","u"].indexOf(str[0])!==-1){
        str+="way";
    }else{    
        while(["a","e","i","o","u"].indexOf(str[0])==-1){
           str+=str[0];
           str=str.slice(1); 
        }
        str+="ay";
    }    
    return str;
}

translatePigLatin("glove");
```

this works:
1.check the string's first letter .if the letter is vowel then is easy for us to complete the word with "way"
2.if the first letter is not vowel,remove the first letter to end.
repeat the loop until the "first" letter is vowel.
3.now the string have changed and we add an another string("ay") to the string's end